# Create NaN rows in pandas dataframe by aligning Dates

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe as shown in the attachment. It contains prices for different dates for 2 unique BondIDs, as shown below:-

```
Quote_Date     BondID     mid_ZSpread    rank
----------     ------     -----------    -----
28-12-2018     AAA        90.9           1
28-12-2018     BBB        30.9           2
31-12-2018     AAA        91.9           1
02-01-2019     AAA        92.9           1
02-01-2019     BBB        31.9           2
```

Notice for the **31st Jan, 2018** - notice only the BondID AAA  has the price. The BondID BBB is missing the price.

How can I write a efficient code to :-

1) align the dates i.e. if get the unique dates

2) then create NaN entries in the "mid_ZSpread" and "overall_rank" columns (as shown below)

```
Quote_Date     BondID     mid_ZSpread    rank
----------     ------     -----------    -----
28-12-2018     AAA        90.9           1
28-12-2018     BBB        30.9           2
31-12-2018     AAA        91.9           1
31-12-2018     BBB        NaN            NaN
02-01-2019     AAA        92.9           1
02-01-2019     BBB        31.9           2
```

Thanks

Comment: Hi. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Comment: [Please don't post images of data and code (or links to them)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html), and for that you need to create a MultiIndex first, where all combinations of QuoteDate and BondID occur [`from_product`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_product.html). If you then `set_index`, you can reindex and Pandas will automatically give `NaN` for unknown values.

```
mi = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df['Quote_Date'].unique(), df['BondID'].unique()])

df.set_index(['Quote_Date', 'BondID']).reindex(mi)
#                    mid_ZSpread  rank
#28-12-2018 AAA         90.9   1.0
#           BBB         30.9   2.0
#31-12-2018 AAA         91.9   1.0
#           BBB          NaN   NaN
#02-01-2019 AAA         92.9   1.0
#           BBB         31.9   2.0
```

Comment: Amazing!! Thanks a lot